# java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: recv failed

Tags: java, networking, ftp

i am a beginner programmer in this networking java concept wherein you connect to a remote ftp server and carry out trivial tasks.

here is my code

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;


public class SimpleOne {

    static String serverName = "ftp.drivehq.com";
    static int port = 21;
    static String username = "CANTSHOW";
    static String password = "CANTSHOW";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        FTPClient ftpc = new FTPClient();
        ftpc.connect(serverName, port);
        int reply = ftpc.getReplyCode();
        String sReply = ftpc.getReplyString();
        if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
        {
            System.out.println("Some error!");
            return;
        }
        boolean success = ftpc.login(username, password);
        if(success)
        {
            System.out.println("Login successful!");
            System.out.println(sReply);
            ftpc.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            String dir=ftpc.printWorkingDirectory();
            System.out.println(dir);
            success = ftpc.changeWorkingDirectory("My Documents");
            if(success)
            {
                System.out.println(ftpc.printWorkingDirectory());
                ftpc.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String remoteFile = "SampleText.txt";
                File localFile = new File("sample.txt");
                OutputStream localOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));
                success=ftpc.retrieveFile(remoteFile, localOutputStream);//<--- ERROR LINE
                localOutputStream.close();
                if(!success)
                {
                    System.out.println("There was some problem in retrieving the file");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("File was downloaded!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Could not change directory!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Login failed!");
        }
    }

}
```

and here is what my output looks like:

```
Login successful!
220 Welcome to the most popular FTP hosting service! Save on hardware, software, hosting and admin. Share files/folders with read-write permission. Visit http://www.drivehq.com/ftp/;

/
/My Documents
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:483)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:608)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.pasv(FTP.java:1007)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:869)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1854)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1845)
    at SimpleOne.main(SimpleOne.java:44)
```

What all i have tried:

1. i googled this issue, found that it was filed as an official bug and Microsoft released a hotfix. i downloaded that hotfix, but the installer said that it was not for my windows version (btw, i use win7 x86 and jdk 1.7.0_67)
2. i updated my windows, and downloaded all updates
3. i allowed java.exe and javaw.exe in my firewall in both inbound and outbound connection types

please help me, i am completely stuck here.

Note: as i am still learning, i haven't written that part of code where you logout and disconnect. i hope it has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: Don't print meaningless error messages like 'some error!'. Print the reply.

Comment: You could try to set -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true. I have seen similar (but not exactly this) permission denieds on windows in combination with some third party software (like VPN clients installed) when v6 was enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it turns out that not only you have to download and install the updates, you also have to restart your pc!

well so i just had to restart it!

problem solved.

thankyou!